# Laravel - $fillable filled, still getting MassAssignmentException

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very peculiar problem. I am trying to create a new entry in my database via Tinker. Whenever I run 
`App\User::find(1)->message()->create(['message' => 'Hello from Coleigh']);` I get a MassASsignmentException. The weird thing is I put the variables name in my fillable property. I don't understand why I am getting this.

I have been Googling for answers, but as you can see from my code, I have added my message field to both fillable properties. I have absolutely no idea why laravel isn't recognizing the message field.

Here are my models

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Message extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['message'];
        public function user() {
            return $this->BelongsTo(User::class);
        }
    }
```

and

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'message'
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function hasRole($name) {
        foreach($this->roles as $role) {
            if ($role->name == $name) {
                return true;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }

    public function deposits() {
        return $this->hasMnay('App\Deposits');
    }

    public function isBlocked()
    {
        if ($this->banned) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message() {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }


}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was related to timestamps. Try putting `public $timestamps = false;` in your Message class. If didn't work please post your MassAssignment exception error

Comment: Didn't work. I get this error: Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/MassAssignmentException with message 'message'

Comment: Why are you not creating the message first and attach it to user?

Comment: I am following a tutorial on YouTube and that's how they did it.

Comment: Try restarting Tinker. Whenever you modify your code, you need to restart Tinker.

Comment: Instead of
`protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'message'
]; `
try with 
`protected $guarded = [];`
to see if you are still getting the exception.

Comment: Can you post your migrations too?

Comment: Just to see if it's an issue with tinker or not, create a new `Route` called `test` (or something like that) and try running you code within the route. If you don't get an error then it'll at least point to an issue with tinker.

Comment: Yes it does work in the brower, so it is an issue with Tinker. Thanks, I'll do some research on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `save`

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$comment = new App\Message(['message' => 'Hello from Coleigh']);

$user->message()->save($comment);
```

Otherwise with create, you'd need to set the relationships id.

Answer (score 1):

In class messsage, you should add one more column in $fillable property.

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your missing `user_id` in Message `$fillable`.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Tried that, no luck